# synchronously select samples from two multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

There are two paired multi-dimensional arrays, A and B.  Both of their shapes are of [1000,30,30,3]

These two arrays are corresponding to each other, i.e., [i,30,30,3] in the first array should correspond to [i,30,30,3] of the second array.

I am trying to sample a pair of two elements from these two arrays synchronously. Moreover, I only want to keep the last three dimensions for the selected elements,

This is what I did

```
sampleA = np.zeros(30,30,3)
sampleB = np.zeros(30,30,3)

sampleIndex= np.random.randint(0,A.shape[0],1)

A1 = A[sampleIndex,:,:,:]
B1 = B[sampleIndex,:,:,:]

sampleA = A1[?,:,:,:]
sampleB = B1[?,:,:,:]
```

Is this the right approach? Are there any better or more efficient ways to do it?

Comment: You can use `A1[0]`, `np.squeeze(A1)`, among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go with this 1-line routine `sampleA,sampleB = random.choice(zip(A,B))`:

```
import numpy as np
import random

A= np.random.rand(1000,30,30,3)
B= np.random.rand(1000,30,30,3)       
sampleA,sampleB = random.choice(zip(A,B))

#### check if the indices are the same: 
A_idx = [idx for idx in range(np.shape(A)[0]) if (A[idx,:,:,:]==sampleA).all()]
B_idx = [idx for idx in range(np.shape(B)[0]) if (B[idx,:,:,:]==sampleB).all()]

print 'The index of sampled array from A is %s which corresponds to index %s in B'%(str(A_idx),str(B_idx))
```

in which sampleA and sampleB corresponds to each other of course:

```
The index of sampled array from A is [919] which corresponds to index [919] in B
```